# What am I doing wrong here? Else if

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I'm having trouble here. It's an assignment, basically I ask a question of what 3+3 is and the user can put the right answer in... 6 and it will say "Correct!" If it's not a number, then it will say "please type in a number..." If it's 5 or 7 then it will say "Very close, try again" if it's anything other than 5 6 or 7 it wills say "incorrect" and if nothing is type in it should say "come on, you can do it." What am I doing wrong here???? Currently all it's doing is saying yes, 6 is correct! even when i type in a different number

```
var question;
question = window.prompt("What's the sum of 3+3?", "");

question = parseFloat(question);
if (isNaN(question)) {
  output = "Please enter a number";
} else if (question = 6) {
  output = "Yes " + question + " is correct!";
} else if (question = 5) {
  output = "Very close, try again!";
} else if (question = 7) {
  output = "Very close, try again!";
} else if (question = null) {
  output = "Come on, you can do it!!";
} else {
  output="Incorrect, Please try again"
}

document.write(output);
```

Comment: `==` is not the same as `=`

Comment: Also 3+3 is 6 so you have to accomodate for the corner case where 3+3=9 ;)

Comment: holy crap, thank you changed it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in @Anik Islam Abhi's answer and the comments `=` **is not the same as** `==`.

`==` is a comparison operator ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality))

`=` is an assignment operator ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment))

Now, what you need to do is decide what means for the user to enter *nothing*?
I will assume you mean any amount of whitespace.

What you can do is always remove all whitespace from the inputed answer and if the user still inputed *nothing* then you know you should print "Come on, you can do it!!"

```js
// get the question and remove all whitespace so we know if the user enter an empty string
var question = window.prompt("What's the sum of 3+3?","").trim().replace(' ','');
    
if (!question) {                              // nothing
    output = "Come on, you can do it!!";
} else if(isNaN(question)) {                  // not a number
output = "Please enter a number";  
} else if (question == 6) {                   // correct answer
    output = "Yes " +question+" is correct!"; 
} else if (question == 5 || question == 7) {  // close answer
    output = "Very close, try again!";    
} else {
    output="Incorrect, Please try again"      // incorrect answer 
}

document.write(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you user question=8 in if which mean you assign 8 to question.

> = means assign and == mean comparing

Try this :

```js
var question; 
question = window.prompt("What's the sum of 3+3?","");

question = parseFloat(question);
if (isNaN(question))
{
    output= "Please enter a number";    
}else if (question==6)
{
    output="Yes " +question+" is correct!"; 
}else if (question==5){
    output="Very close, try again!";    

}else if (question==7){
    output="Very close, try again!";
}else if (question==null){
    output="Come on, you can do it!!";
}

else {output="Incorrect, Please try again"}





document.write(output);
```

Comment: thank you, everything is working now.. except one thing. when nothing is entered it says "please enter a number". How come the null isn't working??

Comment: isNaN means is not a number . null is not a number that's mean it return true and then it show the conditions actions